# Page refresh wipe out the Angularjs $scope variables

Tags: angularjs, session, page-refresh

I'm new to Angularjs, I trying to implement the Facebook login through my Angularjs app. I was successful in implementing it. :)

What I'm doing is, if the login successful I'm setting a variable `logged` to true.

```
//loading the file
$scope.logged = false;

Facebook.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status == 'connected') {
        $scope.logged = true;
        //do some stuff
     }
     else
       $scope.login();
     });
```

But my problem is, if the user refresh the page, the `$scope.logged` variable becomes `false` again and user is asked to re-login.

I'm using a REST API (Rails) as the back end

How can I avoid these kind of situations with Angular?

Comment: You need to remember the `logged` flag somehow. Either By storing the information in database or use `localStorage` API

Comment: Or use something like the [`$cookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) service to store it.

Answer (score 1):

Put logged_in = true to cookieStore in your login method after authentication as below.

```
$cookieStore.put('logged_in',true);
$rootScope.logged_in = true;
```

and in your Controller, do

```
$rootScope.logged_in = $cookieStore.get('logged_in');
```

Now you can use this logged_in variable anywhere in the UI to check if the user is logged in. Make sure to use 'ngCookies' module in your app. and pass the $cookieStore dependency to your controller. You can even keep the user object itself similar to logged_in variable in cookies and retrieve it from cookies. Make sure to do logged_in = false and clear other variables in cookies and set it to blank in your logout method.